# Mailer can't find template, using path to archived release folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

Only in production, action sends email which doesn't get sent citing this issue:

> "Missing template general_mailer/general_email with \"mailer\"  ... 
>   `mail'\n/var/www/thecompany/releases/20160514000058/app/mailers/general_mailer.rb:16:in`
>   general_email

Notice the reference to the dated folder that's too old and no longer on the server.

My mailer code is this:

```
class GeneralMailer < ApplicationMailer
  append_view_path Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'general_mailer')

  def general_email(recipient_name, recipient_email, subject, greeting, pre_link_message, link, link_label, post_link_message, closing, signature)
    ...
    mail(to: "#{@recipient_name} <#{@recipient_email}>", subject: @subject)   
  end    
end
```

I can assure you that in my views, the path to the file is `views/general_mailer/general_email.html.erb`

Can someone help me get the mailer to look in the "current" folder instead please?

Comment: Maybe this is an old thread (application worker or background worker). Did all Ruby processes restart properly after deployment?

Comment: I'm able to see my most recent changes yes.

Comment: Are you using a preloader like Zeus or Spring? If any, stop (and restart) it, then restart you app and try again. They sometimes fail to recognize all relevant code changes themselves.

Comment: As @Raffael said, make sure you don't have any old workers that could have and old running copy of your code. Kill all the workers and restart if you can and if you are indeed using them in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Raffael, I thought about what processes are running. I use Delayed_Job to send emails. Once I stopped and restarted DJ my emails started sending properly. Thank you!

Comment: Exactly the kind of problem I had in mind :) Remember that you can (and should) accept an answer, even if you answered the question yourself.